# Php file chunking - how do i do it properly

Tags: php, guzzle, chunking

Im new to PHP file chunking and uploading.  I was wondering if someone can give me some guidance on how to do it properly.

One of my main questions i have in mind, when uploading chunks, does that last chunk have to be equal to the rest?  i keep getting an error with guzzle when attempting to upload.  everything seems to work fine.  However, when the last chunk hits it pauses for about 15 seconds and then gives this error

Error details: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 56: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

i was wondering if someone can give me some guidance on how to properly perform file chunking upload

below is an example of my code in case someone needs to see it:  thank you in advance.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use Microsoft\Graph\Exception\GraphException;
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
use function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for;

$tenantId = 'tenantid';
$clientId = 'clientid';
$clientSecret = 'secret';

$guzzle = new Client();

$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';

$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());

$accessToken = $token->access_token;

$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token->access_token
];

function uploadLargeFiles($accessToken) {
    $graph = new Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    /** @var Model\UploadSession $uploadSession */
    try {
        $uploadSession = $graph->createRequest("POST",
            "/sites/SITEID/drive/items/ITEMID:/newfile.txt:/createUploadSession")
            ->addHeaders(["Content-Type" => "application/json"])
            ->attachBody([
                "item" => [
                    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" => "replace",
                ]
            ])
            ->setReturnType(Model\UploadSession::class)
            ->execute();
    } catch (GraphException $e) {
        echo "Something bad happened";
    }

    $file = __DIR__ . '/file_50mb.dat';
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    $fileSize = fileSize($file);
    $fileNbByte = $fileSize - 1;
    $chunkSize = 327680*16;
    $fgetsLength = $chunkSize + 1;
    $start = 0;

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $bytes = fread($handle, $fgetsLength);
        $end = $chunkSize + $start;
        if ($end > $fileNbByte) {
            $end = $fileNbByte;
        }
//        $stream = stream_for($bytes);

        echo "start: " . $start . "\n";
        echo "end: " . $end . "\n";
        echo "bytes " . $start . "-" . ($end - 1) . "/" . $fileSize . "\n";
        echo "chunk size: " . ($end - $start) . " bytes, " . (($end - $start) * 0.000001) . " MB" . "\n\n";

        try {
            $res = $graph->createRequest("PUT", $uploadSession->getUploadUrl())
                ->addHeaders([
                    'Connection' => "keep-alive",
                    'Content-Length' => $end - $start,
                    'Content-Range' => "bytes " . $start . "-" . ($end - 1) . "/" . $fileSize,
                    'Accept' => "*/*",
                    'Origin' => "------snip------",
                ])
                ->setReturnType(Model\UploadSession::class)
                ->attachBody($bytes)
                ->execute();
        } catch (GraphException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }

        $start = $end;
    }
}

uploadLargeFiles($accessToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

> One of my main questions i have in mind, when uploading chunks, does
>   that last chunk have to be equal to the rest?

Nope, what matters is `Content-Range` header ([from docs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem-createuploadsession.md)):

> Your app must ensure the total file size specified via `Content-Range` header is the 
>    **same** for all requests. If a byte range
>    declares a different file size, the request will fail.

In your example *last* byte range for `Content-Range` header is calculated incorrectly here:

```
if ($end > $fileNbByte) {
    $end = $fileNbByte;  
}
```

Instead it should be like this:

```
if ($end > $fileNbByte) {
   $end = $fileNbByte + 1;
}
```